# .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5.1 migration issues

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

Some background: I recently upgraded from VS2008 to VS2013 which went off without a hitch. I then updated the target framework for each of the solutions in my project (A web portal, three services, a Data Access Layer, and report library). After changing the framework, I got this error:

```
Error   174 Assembly 'DAL', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[token]' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[token]'
```

So I updated the reference in our Web.Config file to 4.0.0.0:

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[token]"/>
```

This fixed the immediate error (of course) but now I'm faced with 8 fresh errors which are all of this nature:

```
Error   174 The type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[token]'.
```

This is thrown when I call

```
DAL.App_Data.MyEntities me = new DAL.App_Data.MyEntities();
```

I have checked, and both the DAL and the project it is being called from have references to  System.Data.Entity of version 4.0.0.0. DAL has it in the project file and the other has it in the web.config file.

Comment: I assume these compile-time errors? Have you updated the project's reference to `System.Data.Entity`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding binding redirects in your config files?

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.Entity" publicKeyToken="[token]" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Even if VS is telling you that the dll versions are 4.0, double check in your bin folder. It may be hanging onto an older version. You can always delete files from bin and obj folders then rebuild. After rebuilding, again double check what was actually copied to your bin folder to make sure it is the right version.

**Update**

1. In the VS solution explorer, under your project, expand the References folder.
2. Find the entry for System.Data.Entity.
3. If you did not find one, skip to step #5.
4. Right-click the assembly and delete it.
5. Right-click the References folder and click Add Reference
6. Click Assemblies in the left pane, then search for System.Data.Entity
7. Check the box next to System.Data.Entity 4.0.0.0 and click OK.
8. Rebuild the solution and try again.

Comment: I did try adding that dependentAssembly block in, but it did not make a difference. I am looking through our bin/obj files and I don't have anything reminiscent of System.Data.Entity in there, maybe that is part of the issue?

Comment: Yes. If the assembly is not being copied to the bin folder, then ASP.NET cannot find it when running your application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-adding System.Data.Entity dll?
The error says you are still missing that reference.

Comment: I'm sorry- I'm not quite sure what you mean by this- could you be more specific about 're-adding'?

Comment: He probably means delete the old bad reference, the add the correct reference.